# How to use Regex to remove font-family attribute in html?

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have the below HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-align: center;" class="ng-scope" align="center">
    <strong><span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 18pt;'>Some Text</span></strong>
  </p>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope"><span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text.</span></p>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope"><span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text.</span></p>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope"><span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text. </span></p>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope">
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Also over</span>
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Cambria Math","serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>‐</span>
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>the</span>
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Cambria Math","serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>‐</span>
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text.</span>
  </p>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope">
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text </span>
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Some Text.</span>
  </p>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="ng-scope">
    <span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary col-sm-12 col-xs-24 col-md-8"><img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgGSE5XUSzMPLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</div>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;" class="ng-scope"><span style='color: black; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt;'>Signature of Patient or Legal Guardian</span> </p>
     </body>
</html>
```

So, All I need is wherever there is font-family attribute, just remove them and the corresponding Property as well.
So, basically, it should remove starting from font-family upto the next semicolon(;). Using RegEx and in C#/VB will do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's better to use `HtmlAgilityPack` here,because maybe there are some text like this in html,not in `style`,if the fact html just likes your demo,you can also use below Regex to replace

```
font-family:[^;']*(;)?
```

this patten can also match the style not end with `;`,just like `style='font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"'`

Answer (score 0):

Given your html is in a `string`-variable `htmlWithFont`, you could do it like that:

```
var htmkWithoutFont = Regex.Replace(htmlWithFont, "font-family:\\s*\".*\";?", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Regex to match `font-family` and not `mso-bidi-font-family` :

```
(?<=;|"|\s)font-family:[^;']*(;)?
```

this pattern only match `font-family` if it's the first style attribute, or if there is a `;` or a space before